# @Field dot-notation not working (MongoDB & Spring)

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-mongodb

When I store something in MongoDB it is a Map of Key/Values. So when I retrieve it:

JSON:

```
{
  "_id": "d13d5667-e003-4f5f-ba6f-99848d994feb",
  "_class": "org.blah.asset.Asset",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "Hello",
    "status": "Draft"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "headline": "Header",
    "body": "body"
  },
  "something": "awesome"
}
```

Java:

```
@Document(collection="Assets")
public class AssetSearchResult {

    @Id
    private String id;
    @org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field("metadata.name")
    private String name;
    @org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field("something")
    private String status;

...generic getters/setters
```

The "status" field is set to "awesome" as expected, but the name field is null.

Does Spring support this (using **spring-data-mongodb-1.6.2.RELEASE**)?

Thanks

Comment: It's been available since Spring Data MongoDB 1.4 RC1 (see [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/commit/1b83ff0382c9b8452ab3f92e28cbeebf67b70bf5) including test cases). Any chance you elaborate on what "does not work" mean exactly? What code are you trying to execute? What do you expect to happen, what happens instead?

Comment: Could you provide some code please that we can execute to verify this not working?

Comment: Updated it to have source and be a little clearer.

Comment: I was able to get it to work as long as I had the following constructor in conjunction with the Field annotation.  Which to me really defeats the purpose, I might as well just have the 2 maps...avoid all the extra annotations and then have the getters/setters:     @PersistenceConstructor
    public AssetSearchResult(String status, String name) {
     System.out.println(name);
    }